# Android using the wrong parent view when configuring a child view's height set to match_parent

Tags: android, android-layout

In the below code, when I set the first child `LinearLayout`'s height to `match_parent` the height blows up to the size of the screen. I have no idea why this is happening. The parent is the `RelativeLayout`, so shouldn't the height of the first child `LinearLayout` just match whatever the height of the `RelativeLayout` is when its height is set to `match_parent`?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@null">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/vote_container"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="1M"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/vote_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/upvote_button"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="17dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_up"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/number_of_votes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/upvote_button"
            android:hint="100"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/downvote_button"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="17dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/number_of_votes"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Is that you want?

Comment: if i wanted the height of the relativelayout to be match_parent then that's what it would be

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessarily a solution to the problem, but more of a work-around. I simply aligned the top and bottom of the first `LinearLayout` to the second `LinearLayout`'s -- @id/vote_container. Assuming the first `LinearLayout`'s height never needs to grow larger than the second `LinearLayout`'s height, this shouldn't be a problem. If it does, I could just reverse the constraint relationship between the two of them.

The reason the code in question doesn't work is because the `RelativeLayout`'s height is set to `wrap_content` and the first `LinearLayout`'s height is set to `match_parent`, so in order to calculate the height of the parent the height of the children is determined but in order to calculate the height of the first child the height of the parent is determined i.e. recursive relationship is created and `Android` doesn't handle it intuitively.

What happens in this case is that the hierarchy of parents are searched through until one with a height other than `wrap_content` is found, and the value for that parent is used for the first `LinearLayout`'s height. In my case, the `RelativeLayout` parent had one other parent, and that was a `LinearLayout` with the height also set to `wrap_content`, so the only parent with a value for height other than `wrap_content` was the super view -- the view that all other views are placed in; and that view's height is simply the size of the screen.

This is the reason my `LinearLayout`'s height was blowing up to the size of the screen.

Comment: This helped with a somewhat similar problem involving a TableRow with nested LinearLayout (horizontal) with two LinearLayouts (vertical). I took out the hozontal LinearLayout because TableRow already is a horizontal LinearLayout and it found the correct parent.